# Is there a way to hash security data in Spring Boot logs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I have logs like:

`Dec 24, 15:50:45.234 | DEBUG ...: client_id=[123] accessToken=[123123]`

How can I hash or mask these security values in logs in a Spring Boot?

Comment: Remove the log line from the code, or set the log level upper than `DEBUG`

Comment: Thank you @Zorglube, it would work for me, but I have a task to do so with any logs in application and I can't be sure that some library will not pass some sensitive data on INFO level.